US citizen going to Italy, cruising from Greece to Turkey and back to Athens, do I need a Schengen visa?
I am US citizen going to Italy, to Athens to join cruise of islands and to Turkey back to Athens, do I need a Schengen visa?

https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44541/american-allowance-in-schengen-area-vs-having-a-schengen-visa-in-schengen-area is not the duplicate I know must be on the site but it does answer your question, as US citizen you do not need a visa for the Schengen countries, but there is a maximum stay of 90 days in each 180 day period.

US citizens do not need and in practice cannot get a Schengen short-stay visa. For all stays that fall under the Schengen visa system (i.e. stays of less than 90 days in any 180-day period), US citizens can present themselves to the border and enter without a visa. As long as the total stay does not exceed the maximum duration and you meet all the usual requirements, you are also allowed to leave and reenter as often as you like so that stopping in Turkey in the middle of the cruise does not create any special issue for you.
